# How to setup docker compose connect apache-superset with influxdb step by step?

Tags: influxdb, apache-superset

```
# curl -v -k https://localhost:8086/api/v2/ping
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8086...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8086 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```